# Can I use Win32 APIs in a WinObjC app?

Tags: objective-c, winapi, winobjc

I'm porting some ObjC/FoundationKit code to Windows using WinObjC. Impressed so far (well done MS!). Can I use Win32 APIs in the project?  When I try to simply include "windows.h" (in a .m file) I then get errors which seem to suggest ObjC compilation has been disabled for the rest of the file (unexpected @ in program). Any ideas? I'm  guessing it's something simple.

It's been 12+ years since I've done any Win32 work so maybe windows.h isn't even relevant any more?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's disabling Objective-C? That is, can you do, say, `@class ClassThatDoesNotEixst;` before including `windows.h` and it will work? And no, `windows.h` is still relevant to Windows *desktop app* programming, at least.

Comment: Also how are you building your project, from within Visual Studio or via command-line? If the former, what type of project is this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using VS. The problem can be reproduced using the HelloUI sample app. Just include <windows.h> after the #import <UIKit>.

Comment: That example seems to be for an iOS app, not for a Windows program. I wonder if you can invoke the compiler directly to build Windows software...

Comment: According to MS's wiki there is support for calling Windows APIs directly: https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki  (scroll down about half way).

Comment: Okay, so it is possible. That wiki page describes writing programs for the Windows Runtime and Universal Windows Platform, which isn't older windows.h desktop programming. But I don't see why it wouldn't be possible... What error do you get if you have `@class xxx;` before `#include <windows.h>`? I'm wondering if there might be something else getting in the way... I can personally try myself at a later date (would need to set up Windows 10 first).

Comment: @class before windows.h works fine. After you've included it though you'll get errors when the compiler encounters anything ObjC related. I've encountered so many issues with the IDE/SDK though I'm happy to wait till the tools are a little more mature before I dive back into this.